# Equals operator for zeros (BigDecimal / Double) in Java

Tags: java, double, precision, bigdecimal, zero

A few interesting observations w.r.t equals operator on 0 and 0.0

1. `new Double(0.0).equals(0)` returns false, while `new Double(0.0).equals(0.0)` returns true.
2. `BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0))` returns false, while `BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(0))` returns true.

Looks like the string comparison is being done in both the cases. Could anyone throw some light on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

BigDecimal 'equals' compares the value and the scale. If you only want to compare values (0 == 0.0) you should use compareTo:

```
BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0)) == 0 //true
BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) == 0 //true
```

See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

As for the Double comparison, as explained by other answers, you are comparing a Double with an Integer in `new Double(0.0).equals(0)`, which returns `false` because the objects have different types. For reference, the [code for the equals method in JDK 7](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Double.java.html#731) is:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof Double)
           && (doubleToLongBits(((Double)obj).value) ==
                  doubleToLongBits(value));
}
```

In your case, `(obj instanceof Double)` is false.

Answer (score 7):

1. The 0 in your first expression is interpreted as an `int`, which may be autoboxed into an `Integer`, but not to a `Double`. So the type of the two is different, hence they are not equal. OTOH `0.0` is a `double`, which is autoboxed into a `Double`, so the two operands are deemed equal.
2. BigDecimals also contain a scale (i.e. number of digits to the right of the decimal separator dot). `BigDecimal.ZERO` has the value of "0", so its scale is 0. Hence it is not equal to "0.0", whose scale is 1.
   If you want to compare values, use [`BigDecimal.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29):

   ```
   BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0)) == 0
   BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) == 0
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Double(0.0).equals(0); //false
```

as the argument you passed is integer. and the **equels()** in **Double** class checks whether the argument is od instance **Double** or not using **instance of** operator.

The **Double**'s **equals()** method.

```
if (!(argument instanceof Double))
  return false;
```

The argument you passed is **integer**, which is not instance of **Double**, so it returns false.

Answer (score 1):

new Double(0.0).equals(0) is actually boxed as something like this:

```
new Double(0.0).equals(Integer.valueOf(0))
```

Double.equals(...) will never return true unless given another Double instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Double(0.0).equals(0)
```

This line compares a double value of 0 (which is not exact zero) with integer of 0.

```
BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0))
```

BigDecimal will compare the scale length in the equals operation.

Answer (score 0):

For performance considerations BigDecimal, BigInteger caches small values 
0 to 15 in case of BigDecimal (without fractions)

BigDecimal.ZERO  will be    new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO, 0,  0, 1)
& valueOf method typically picks up from cache for 0 to 15 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
please try doublevalue instead of compareto if you feel is not as beautiful and readable as or simply need an alternative like below:

BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.00");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.0");
BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal("0");

if(a.doubleValue()==BigDecimal.ZERO.doubleValue()) {
System.out.println("a equals");
}

if(b.doubleValue()==BigDecimal.ZERO.doubleValue()) {
System.out.println("b equals");
}

if(c.doubleValue()==BigDecimal.ZERO.doubleValue()) {
System.out.println("c equals");
}
```

Comment: Transforming a BigDecimal to a double might result in loss of precision and a non-zero but close to zero BigDecimal turned into a Double might become 0. You should compare using the `compareTo` method in BigDecimal