# Java: check if value of oracle field type NUMBER(6,4) is equal to 0

Tags: java, oracle, double, bigdecimal

In an oracle database I have a field of type NUMBER(6,4).
By default in database it's value is set as 0 (or should it be 0.0000?).

In java class I need to check if this value is 0 or not. 
Currently I have this:

```
double feePercent = clientCardMemberGroup.getFeePerc();
if (feePercent != 0) {
...
}
```

This is not the correct way to do. I would like to know how I can use BigDecimal to check if the value from database is either 0 (or 0.0 or 0.00 or 0.000 or 0.0000). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use BigDecimal use ResultSet.getBigDecimal to retrieve data from DB. And to compare values you need to use BigDecimal.compareTo() method. 
`public int compareTo(BigDecimal val)` returns -1 if the BigDecimal is less than val, 1 if the BigDecimal is greater than val and 0 if the BigDecimal is equal to val.
To caompare with zero you can use constant BigDecimal.ZERO. So in your case

```
BigDecimal feePercent = clientCardMemberGroup.getFeePerc();
if (feePercent.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0) {
...
}
```

Comment: Looks to be like a great solution! Will it also return values that are 0,12345 correctly?

Comment: Yes. Why not. If you are not going to have many multiply, divide,etc operations with big accuracy - use primitives it is enough for Number(6,4)

Comment: actually this percent value will be used to determine exact fees. F.e.fee is 3, percent value is 0,1234 so the fee could be something like 0,00369. Will BigDecimal be correct for this?

Comment: Yes. It will. Please remember about constrictor - new BogDecimal(0.1234) and new BigDecimal("0.1234") return you different values. Trying to find proper arcticle for you ....

Comment: please read the tutorial http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial to do not make mistakes in future

Answer (score 1):

```
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("0.0000000000000000000");
     if((bd2.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO))==0){
                System.out.println("Inside");
            }
```

reference:
[Equals operator for zeros (BigDecimal / Double) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992006/equals-operator-for-zeros-bigdecimal-double-in-java)